# Ratio - volume of a pyramid $ABCF$ to volume of a cuboid $ABCDEFGH$

Tags: volume

Let's suppose we have a cuboid $ABCDEFGH$ and now we cut the pyramid $ABCF$ of that cuboid.

What is the ratio of volume of the pyramid to the volume of the original cuboid?

Is it $1\over4$ or $1\over3$?

Comment: Define "cuboid".  Under [Wikipedia's definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cuboid), the ratio could be anything - just move points $D$, $E$, $G$, and $H$ around to change the volume of the cuboid but leave the pyramid's volume unchanged.

Comment: in French: un prisme rectangulaire droit, un cuboïde carré, 
une boîte carrée, un prisme carré droit, un prisme carré; in Spanish: un Ortoedro; in German: ein Quader

Answer (score 1):

Your subsequent comment indicates that you’re talking about a cuboid in the narrower sense, i.e., a right (or rectangular) cuboid. Let the base dimensions of the cuboid be $a$ and $b$, and let $c$ be its height. The pyramid has as base the $\triangle ABC$, whose area is $\frac12ab$, and height $c$. Its volume is one-third that of the corresponding cylinder, so its volume is $$\frac13\cdot\frac12abc=\frac16abc\;,$$ $\frac16$ the volume of the cuboid.

[This image](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File%3aMarching_tetrahedrons.png) and the first one on [this page](http://www.ics.uci.edu/~eppstein/projects/tetra/) show a decomposition of a cube into six pyramids of this type.